# Swift Core Data Variable Issue

Tags: swift, core-data

I am having a syntax issues I just cannot figure out. I do not have a strong Swift back ground, so the answer my be easy (I hope.) So, here is the snippet:

```
public func getLatestDate()-> NSDate? {

    var request = NSFetchRequest()
    var entity = NSEntityDescription.entityForName("Event", inManagedObjectContext: self.managedObjectContext)

    request.entity = entity

    let sortDescriptor = NSSortDescriptor(key: "timeStamp", ascending: false)
    let sortDescriptors = [sortDescriptor]

    request.sortDescriptors = sortDescriptors

    var error: NSError? = nil

    do {
        let results = try self.managedObjectContext.executeFetchRequest(request)
    } catch {
        fatalError("Failed to fetch employees: \(error)")
    }

    var date: NSDate?
    if results != nil {
        let managedObject: NSManagedObject = results![0] as NSManagedObject
        date = managedObject.valueForKey("timeStamp") as? NSDate
    }

    return date
}
```

The problem is that `if results != nil` and the `results` on the following line are throwing an error stating:

> Use of unresolved identifier 'results'

How do I resolve this issue?

Thank you.

-Matt

Answer (score 1):

You're declaring `results` here:

```
do {
    let results = try self.managedObjectContext.executeFetchRequest(request)
} catch {
    fatalError("Failed to fetch employees: \(error)")
}
```

So you can see that it's being done within a `do-catch` block. That means that where you try to use it is out of the scope where it was defined, so it can't see it at all. By the time you get to `if results != nil`, it's already gone out of scope and is gone.

Answer (score 0):

in addition to Gavin: this will work cause of the reason, thar Gavin mentioned

```
do {
    let results = try self.managedObjectContext.executeFetchRequest(request) 
    if results != nil {
        let managedObject: NSManagedObject = results![0] as NSManagedObject
        date = managedObject.valueForKey("timeStamp") as? NSDate
    }

} catch {
    fatalError("Failed to fetch employees: \(error)")
}
```